# Question on relationship between Ax = 0 and Ax = b

Tags: linear-algebra, homogeneous-equation

This is a true or false question.

"If **x**1 and **x**2 are two solutions of the nonhomogeneous linear system A**x** = **b**, then **x**1 - **x**2 is a solution of the corresponding homogeneous linear system."

Now I know that the general solution of A**x** = **b** can be found by adding a specific solution (**x**1 or **x**2) to the general solution of A**x** = **0** but this question seems to suggest that **x**1 - **x**2 gives you a specific solution to A**x** = **0**. Why is this? I think everything is here to make the link but I can't seem to make it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are solutions of $Ax=b$, we get

$$A(x_1-x_2)=Ax_1-Ax_2=b-b=0.$$

We are done !

Comment: Well, that was easy...in retrospect. Thanks, Fred.